# Email signature - header banner

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to add a header to my emails. This would be an image and the way I want it displayed would be [banner][email body][signature]

But the problem is the image is displayed with two empty rows above it and the cursor placed on the first. This is in Outlook.

If anyone know how I can fix this, I'd appreciate it.

P.S. I need this to work in Thunderbird as well.

I created three div blocks, one for the banner, one for the email body and one for the signature, with an empty paragraph line in the middle div block. I thought this is how it would work, but no...

```
<div>
<table class=MsoNormalTable width='100%' role='presentation' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 style='background: none;border-width: 0;margin: 0;mso-padding-alt: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;'>
        <tbody>
            <tr valign='middle'>
                <td valign='middle'>
                    <a href='https://google.com' style='text-decoration: none;'>
                        <img src='xxx' width=720 height=74 name='Banner' style='vertical-align: middle;display:block;' alt=''/>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div style='background: none; mso-padding-alt: 15px 0 0 0; padding:15px 0 0 0;'>
<p> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're bothering with a table at all if the only thing going into it is the image?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably because I read that email clients deal with how things are arranged in a table better than with div blocks. But I don't think this causes my problems.

Comment: You mentioned `I created three div blocks` but you have two div's only in the code in your post. Also why not use a table with 3 rows rather than 3 div's for each row?

Comment: It seemed pointless to put the code for the 3rd div block here. That contains the signature and it works perfectly. As for putting them in a 3 row table, it seemed weird to have to write your text in a table cell. I thought div blocks would be more intuitive.

Comment: It's not pointless. Your question was asking for help on 3 rows and code supplied was of 2 so I asked. Also you are coding for email not web. Emails are done with tables u less you are using the hybrid method of coding then you use divs.

Comment: I'm not having problems with that part of the code though. It's just a signature which is to be placed at the footer of the email. I made it with tables by the way and it behaves as it should on multiple platforms. However, I didn't know how I could place a banner in the header and force the email client to put the cursor under it. Both Outlook and Thunderbird generate two new rows at the beginning of the new email and that's where they automatically place the cursor. Is there a way to change this habit ? Otherwise, it's troublesome to have to explain to people they have to delete the 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.demo
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-div">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" width='100%' role='presentation' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=2 style='background: none;border-width: 0;margin: 0;mso-padding-alt: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;'>
    <tbody  class="demo">
  <tr valign='middle'>
     <td valign='middle'>
         <a href='https://google.com' style='text-decoration: none;'>
            <img src='demoimg.jpg' width=100% height="400px;" name='Banner' style='vertical-align: middle;display:block;' alt='banner here...'/>
         </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <h2>email body here.....</h2>
     </td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="signature demo" style='background: none; mso-padding-alt: 15px 0 0 0; padding:15px 0 0 0;'>
<p>signature here....</p>
</div>
```

i think your problem is solved through update width="100%" and add second tr tag for email body

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a table with 3 rows?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The problem with Outlook at least, is that it places line breaks before all of this and the cursor on those new lines (when you start to write an email). Same in Thunderbird actually...

I need this for a company signature, so I can't tell each employee to delete manually the extra rows and move the cursor under the banner each time they write an email. It takes time and it's not...elegant, let's say.
I thought that using div blocks will tell the email client to behave better...but no...
What do you think ? How could I solve this ?

Comment: div is most useful than table and also responsive.., so you use  divs than table in 3 rows..